# Index array of a list of strings

Tags: python

I have a "list" of strings and I need to get a index array of all the elements of the list that equal a pattern.

I don't need to use a python list, I can use another data structure, but I don't know which.

Example:

```
my_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'foo', 'goodbye']
pattern = 'foo'
```

And my desired result is something like:

```
my_mask = [True, False, False, True, False]
```

So I can then index a numpy array with this mask:

```
selected_items = my_array[my_mask]
```

However, having a list and doing:

```
my_list == pattern
```

Doesn't return a mask, just False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `numpy` solution:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = np.array(['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'foo', 'goodbye'])
pattern = 'foo'

mask = my_list == pattern
# array([ True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

my_list[mask]
# array(['foo', 'foo'], 
#       dtype='<U7')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the looping yourself, Python containers do not support vectorized operations, so something like:

```
[x == pattern for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a *list comprehension* to get the desired list as:

```
>>> my_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'foo', 'goodbye']
>>> pattern = 'foo'

>>> [item==pattern for item in my_list]
[True, False, False, True, False]
```

Here I am iterating on the `my_list` list and checking equality of each element with `pattern`, and storing the result (True/False) in new list created through List Comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to create the desired list:

```
mask = [x==pattern for x in my_list]
```

which creates

```
[True, False, False, True, False]
```

alternatively you can use numpy arrays, which support the `==` operator the way you wanted to use it for lists:

```
my_list = np.array(my_list)
my_list == pattern
>>>array([ True, False, False,  True, False])
```

However if you want a list of indices, then you could do something like:

```
[i for i,x in enumerate(my_list) if x==pattern]
>>>[0, 3]
```

`enumerate` creates tuples of `(index, element_at_index)` from your list. In the code `i` is the index and `x` the element at that index. We save in the new list now the index `i` if the elment eqauls pattern